# Custom CSS not applying to email field in Enfold WP theme on iPhones

Tags: ios, css, iphone, safari, mobile-safari

I've made a fairly simple "Coming soon" page for a client <kbd>[here](http://tipperarydistillery.ie/)</kbd> and I have a very strange problem. Normally I'm the "go-to" CSS specialist of everyone I personally know, but on this one I am out of resources/ideas trying to figure it out.

On iPhones, using the default browser (Safari), the `email` input, which has a `type="text"`, just like the `name` field, displays a white border instead of a blue one. The client reported the problem (she has an iPhone6 - not sure if S or not) and I tested it myself with on an ancient piece (4s) we just keep around the office for testing. For all I know, `border-color` is a CSS1 property, same as `border-width` and `border-style`. They are all applied explicitly so, basically no browser in the world should have a problem rendering it.

I haven't been able to reproduce the issue in any emulator or online snippet tool, so I don't see any point in posting code here. I'm assuming someone with proper iOS/Safari debugging tools/environment might be able to inspect the element and see why the CSS doesn't apply. I also tested the CSS for errors. The one I applied (child theme) is bug free. The parent theme CSS reports some issues but they're mostly vendor prefixes. But it's a good, well designed and well coded theme: Enfold by Kriesi.

---

EDIT: On further testing I just discovered the `color` property is also set to  white too, when it should be the same blue: `#255AA8`.

Any idea on how I could debug this (on a Windows 10 machine) is also welcome.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem... in the themes's `.js`.

Apparently, it detects if on mobile (somehow they do it properly -  as the script doesn't fire in emulators) and if the field requires an email address, the `type` attribute is changed from `text` to `email` via js, so the email keyboard layout pops up when user inputs their email.

Adding

```
#top div .av-light-form input[type="email"] {
}
```

to my list of selectors did the job.